# What is the kind of graph for number of partitions of an integer

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How do you call a graph showing the count of a partition of a specific size?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a histogram. It is showing the distribution of partition sizes.